# WCF compilation error on CI server: Microsoft.VisualStudio.ServiceModel.targets not found

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2012, continuous-integration

I am getting this error on my CI server:

> error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\WCF\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ServiceModel.targets" was not found

It seems my WCF service library project references that file, but the VisualStudio folder on `Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft` doesn't contain a WCF folder.

I guess I need to install something on the server.

What do I need to install?

Comment: Installing microsoft windows SDK should work - For windows server 2008 link is - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11310

Comment: @MilanRaval Tried that, still same error

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Well this ruined my morning, but let's not allow it to ruin anyone else's. I couldn't find this information anywhere else. You need to copy a few files from a development machine with VS Pro 2012.

As aphexddb mentions, you need to copy some targets from `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\WCF` to the same location on your CI server.

This then references an assembly called `Microsoft.VisualStudio.ServiceModel.Core`. You can find this assembly in either the GAC or in the IDE directory at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE`.

Copy this to your CI server and execute `gacutil.exe -i Microsoft.VisualStudio.ServiceModel.Core.dll`

This was enough to fix it for me.

This isn't the first time I found targets missing from my VS express install in my CI server. I can't help but feel that there is some sort of package I can download from somewhere that fills all this in. Does anyone know of such a thing? If not, perhaps we should create one.

Comment: The package you are looking for would be: [Agents for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38186) or [Microsoft Build Tools 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40760)
Except for that this does not fix the targets for WCF library projects.

Comment: or [Agents for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40750)
It's quite unclear what these installers install.
(it's still ruining my morning; I hesitate to install the library using gacutil as this might ruin a fellow system administrators' morning in the future)

Comment: @RobertSirre It was unclear from your comments: did installing the above "Agents for Microsoft Visual Studio 201X" packages rectify the problem?

Comment: This is still broken in the Build Tools 2015 Update 3 installation. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3103264/build-tools-2015-update-3-unable-to-build-c-web-service-project

Comment: Microsoft seems unwilling to fix that until someone gives them a sample project..

Comment: Still the same issue in VS2017; although the MSBuild location is now different. Mine is at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WCF` (but 'Professional' be different for different flavours). Just copying the files worked for me, I didn't need to GAC anything.

Answer (score 19):

Can still happen on vs2019

> error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual
>   Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\WCF\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ServiceModel.targets"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk.

WCF is not installed by default as part of 'ASP.NET and web development' workload. To fix this,

On visual studio installer > modify > individual components tab, search for wcf, check, modify - the .targets file gets now installed, msbuild builds ok.

MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '16.3.2.50909' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\bin'

Comment: This was my problem in VS 2019, and this answer fixed the problem.

Comment: This also fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this with Visual Studio 2017, for me the resolution was to modify my installation of Visual Studio to include the Windows Communication Foundation components.

Comment: The thing is, ideally, CI servers should have MSBuild on it; but shouldn't need Visual Studio itself.

Answer (score 5):

Extract [this](http://druss.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Microsoft.VisualStudio.ServiceModel.zip)  file into folder

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\WCF

The file name is "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ServiceModel.targets"

Answer (score 3):

Now you can solve the problem using the Nuget Package MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets
so the build process does not require any change to the build server.

Install-Package MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets

Details:

- remove the element for "ServiceModels.targets" in the .csproj file
- remove the target WebApplication from the build command (in yaml)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using VS 2022 build tools, it is no longer in the individual components section. It is on the first tab "Workloads", included in ".NET desktop build tools", you will see it in the list on the right-hand side when you select it.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this same issue. Did the following to resolve:

1. Installed the Microsoft [Web Platform Installer](https://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/webpi.ashx/getinstaller/WDeploy.appids)
2. Copied Directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\WCF" from dev laptop with Visual Studio 2012 to the build server

Comment: I did try copying and WCF targets to the CI Server and doesn't work. The web platform installer is just an application to retrieve other packages but doesn't deal with WCF libraries or any SDK library at all.

Comment: You need to add it to the GAC `gacutil.exe -i Microsoft.VisualStudio.ServiceModel.Core.dll`

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same error - my issue was that MS has modified the way MSBuild looks for the versions of VS in the build process template.

Make sure to use the right build process template.
If using TFS2013 and VS2013 use TfvcTemplate.12.xaml

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same error. In my case, the problem was that my Visual Studio 2008 project didn't get upgraded correctly, probably due to files being marked "read-only" by my source control.  To fix it, I loaded the solution in Visual Studio 2015 with everything checked out.

The specific line in the .csproj file changed from

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\WCF\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ServiceModel.targets" />
```

To

```
<Import Project="$(WcfServiceModelTargetPath)\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ServiceModel.targets" />
```